# Elasticsearch, join data type: single mapping type for parent and child fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to implement Parent/Child relationships between two entities `X` and `Y` with completely different set of fileds each, in Elasticsearch `6.3.2`. I was going to create two mapping files for each of the associations and define `_parent` field on child side.

But according to ES documentation, starting with 6.x multiple types are no longer supported in a single index.

So with this restriction, should I put all the fields for entity `X` and `Y` into a single mapping file? If so, what if I have same field, say `name` in both entities. Should I name them `x.name` and `y.name`? What is the approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parent child documents reside in the same index.

Example

```
Parent document:
Post index-name/_doc/1  
{
  "my_id": "1",
  "text": "This is a question",
  "my_join_field": "question" 
}

Child Document:
Post index-name/_doc/2
{
  "my_id": "2",
  "text": "This is answer",
  "my_join_field": {
    "name": "answer", 
    "parent": "1" 
  }
}
```

Above have same fields, they can have different fields. In which case fields will be null in one document and have value in other. [Join type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html) is used to identify parent and child document

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got the part about `my_join_field`. In my case, I will create mapping type manually, hence I curious whether it should contain all the fields from the entities. Based on your answer, it should. Going back to you sample, let's assume I created first `question` document where  `my_id` filed has `long` type, and than I create `answer` document where `my_id` has `String` type. I will get exception in that case, won't I? So, should I handle such type difference by providing fields name with different prefix or OSLT?

Comment: @I.Domshchikov Since it is single index, there can be only one datatype for a field. In your case either create two fields "parent_my_id" and "child_my_id" or store both as text/long (same type) and handle conversion client side. Parent and client are just different documents of same index. Also while creating child documents you need to specify routing as child should exist in same shard as parent